# window.onload = function(){}; limited to contain certain amount of lines?

Tags: javascript, function, window, onload

I have this very odd problem. I seem to have reached some sort of cap on the

```
window.onload = function () {

//all my stuff;

}
```

I know it was not the brightest idea to do that in the first place but yeah I do not want to recode old work from the past. I wanted to update te code, but then I found out that my opening and closing brackets frome the window.onload function do not match anymore after a certain point. I tested this in jsfiddle, notepad++ and sublime text. I am 100% positive that it has nothing to do with any mistakes on my part. I was exactly able to trace the problem and where it happened in my code. I could just add one line more and the brackets did not match anymore.

Thing is whitespace did not acount to the problem only lines with code.

Any ideas?

Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f22gb3L4/

Comment: You say you were able to test it in jsfiddle.  Perhaps you could include that jsfiddle?

Comment: This is unlikely a problem that can be solved with a theoretical discussion.  You will have to show us somehow exactly what you add to suddenly make it fail.  If you can demonstrate that failure in a jsFiddle, even better.  If you have tens of thousands of lines of code in one function, you're kind of getting what you deserve as the very first thing I'd do if I had to work on that is break it up into several smaller functions all called from the main one.

Comment: I just tried to run a 100000 line onload event handler, and it works in IE, Firefox and Chrome. Do you have more lines than that?

Comment: I know that whenever I'm *100% positive it has nothing to do with any mistakes on my part* that usually means I screwed up. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: No it is not 100000 codes of line, maybe 300. The thing is it runs well, but the brackets do not match after a certain point. I will see if i can come up with a fiddle and pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Added the fiddle in the question.

Comment: So your "issue" is not with the code at all but just the highlighting of matching brackets in your code editor...

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yup, but it is consistent with different editors

Answer (score 0):

Yeah man you can do this

```
        // Instead of this
        window.onload = function() {
            console.log('hello dog');
            console.log('hello Cat');
        }
        // use this
        window.onload = helloDog;

        function helloDog() {
            console.log('hello dog');
            helloCat();
        }
        function helloCat() {
            console.log('hello cat');
        }
```

The window.load takes only a single function so use the benefit provided by the language it self and you can organise your code alot better, the shitty thing here is pollution these functions will be globally exposed, you can namespace them to fix this issue.

You can also use [jshint](http://jshint.com), it will improve your code it's made for that